# Is there a way to make a 2 digit year into a 4 digit year in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I started learning r. We have to tidy up a dataset. The date column has the date as May_08. The column has to be separate by month and year. Ex: from May_08 to May 2008. This is the code that I have so far.

```
dataset %>%
  separate(date, c("month","year"))
```

Comment: You got some good answers but just as a general suggestion: Store the dates as date. I.e. read the date in using `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct` and leave it like that. Only if you want to print it (or need it for another reason as a string), only then use `strftime` or `format` to bring it into desired format. That way you can make full use of `R`s date handling capabilities (i.e for plotting, doing math with dates, sorting etc)

Comment: @akrun, to be fair, both of your (you and jay.sf) answers are generally good enough given the ambiguity of two digit years. They both fall prey to some inputs, too. In my opinion, I see no "community bias" in either of the first comments (though I wonder if subsequent comments have since been deleted and therefore not visible to me).

Comment: @r2evans I would say that the 2 digit year is always an issue because there are some edge cases and unless the OP specifies it correctly, it can go either way to 19 or 20 for some cases.   To nitpick that and post below my solution is fine but the other solution also have the same issue some way or another.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `strftime`. Just paste a day in front of the string beforehand.

```
x <- "May_08"

strftime(as.Date(paste(1, x), format="%d %b_%y"), "%b %Y")
# [1] "May 2008"
```

Comment: @akrun, how so? `as.Date(paste(1, "May_33"), format="%d %b_%y")` yields `"2033-05-01"`, is that incorrect?

Comment: @akrun, I'm not judging, I was commenting that your *"It won't work"* is perhaps missing the qualifier of *"depending on expected outcome"*.

Comment: @akrun, I'm not commenting on that, I'm commenting on this. Not everybody reads all answers and all comments to all answers, so I thought it fair to ask what doesn't work about that input for this answer. (Especially now that you've deleted your answer so that all related context is lost.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/).

```
x <- "May_08"
library(lubridate)
paste(month(parse_date_time(x, "my"), label = T), year(parse_date_time(x, "my")), sep = " ")
# [1] "May 2008"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the year breaking 20th century from 21st century years in your series, a simple `ifelse` statement should do. In the example, 1990 is the breaking year, so:

```
yrs <- c(91,94,97,00,03,06,09,12,15,18,21)
yrs <- ifelse(yrs>90, yrs+1900, yrs+2000)
> print(yrs)
[1] 1991 1994 1997 2000 2003 2006 2009 2012 2015 2018 2021
```